# My logins section for access via google is not localized

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, localization, russian-stackoverflow

In the profile page on *My Logins* settings tab, the word "used" actually is not used in localization.

> [image: used]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string will be in Transifex whenever the strings are imported from Q&A next time: `used $when$`.